# Gulp command stops with Error: spawn ENOTDIR

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

*I recognize that there are many similar questions, but none with a solution that I can find.*

I am trying to compile Sass and JS but am getting the following error:

```
Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    ... and so on...
```

It appears that the choke point is the `return sass(...)` statement. My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    notify      = require('gulp-notify'),
    autoprefix  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    source_sass = 'assets/sass/',
    target_css  = 'public/css/',
    source_js   = 'assets/js/',
    target_js   = 'public/js/';

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return sass(source_sass + 'main.scss', {style: 'compressed'})
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(target_css))
        .pipe(notify('CSS processed.'));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(source_js + '**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(target_js))
        .pipe(notify('JS processed.'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(source_sass + '**/*.scss', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(source_js + '**/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'watch']);
```

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
- Ruby v2.0.0p481
- Gem v2.0.14
- Node v0.12.3
- NPM v2.9.1
- Gulp v3.8.11

Comment: I rolled back to Node v0.10.31 and all is well. I don't know what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back to Node v0.10.31 and all is well.